# argparse coexistsnce of required args and subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

**Problem:** I have a parser that has 1 required arg and a subparser that accepts 3 args of which 2 are required when that sub parser is invoked

As follows

**Code:**

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--foo", type=str, required=True, help="foo help")
subparsers=parser.add_subparsers(help="Sub parsers")
mysubparser =  subparsers.add_parser("a", help="a subparser")
mysubparser.add_argument("-b", "--bar", type=str, required=True, help="bar help")
mysubparser.add_argument("-bz", "--baz", type=str, required=True, help="baz help")
mysubparser.add_argument("-bzg", "--bazinga", action="store_true", help="bazinga help")
```

**What I tried:**
my problem is that 
`python myscript.py -f "hi" a -b "hi" -bz "hi"` works but `python myscript.py a -b "hi" -bz "hi" -f "hi"` doesn't. Do required args have to be specified first? I think it looks a bit clunky the first way. is there a way this can be fixed?

I want both versions to work. Or a better alternative to doing things this way

Comment: Once you give the subcommand, any option is treated as belonging to the corresponding subparser. Arguments for the main parser *must* be given before the subcommand.

Comment: Right, I was hoping there would be some kind of workaround, Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Some people prefer to define `--foo` for each subparser.  In part it's a question of logic - does `foo` have more meaning to the main parser, or to the subparsers.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say. foo would be actually required for every sub parser therefore I guess I should add it to every sub parser with a method. Thanks :)

Comment: FYI: This is the same way that `git` behaves (arguments for the `git` command itself come before the subcommand and its arguments).  IIRC, other command-line parsers (like `click`) also behave this way.  What I'm getting at here is that you might be out of luck because many tools expect it to behave the way `argparse` is behaving :(